# Flutter using GlobalKey to trigger another states function

Tags: flutter, dart, key

Basic App to reproduce the error has two widget

Home Widget contains a gesture detector triggering the following function:

```
GlobalKey<MainMapState> mapKey = GlobalKey<MainMapState>();

void getCurrentLocation() async{ // I am using async property for something different but it not our concern right now
        mapKey.currentState.asdd();
      }
```

MainMap is a stateful widget and it's state contains the following function:

```
void asdd(){
    print("triggered");
  }
```

As a result I am getting this [image: error]

Note: I am using GlobalKey to animate CameraPosition to my current location on GoogleMap widget which is inside the MainMapState

Comment: Did you pass global key to your stateful widget and called super() constructor with it?

Comment: @MikhailPonkin can you give an code example on my Mainmap widget(not state) I have the following code: `(class MainMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainMap({ Key key }) : super(key: key);)`

Comment: constructor is looking good. Another thing to try is just to simply add check before calling state methods  `if(mapKey.currentState != null && mapKey.currentState.mounted)`. If it still does not help you - please provide more code

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't have enough reputation points to merely comment on your post.

Based on the error you are receiving I suspect you have the same issue to which I have yet to find a correct answer.  A couple of alternate approaches are listed on my same question as noted at link:

[How to smoothly update a Flutter AnimatedList without using a GlobalKey.currentState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56896814/how-to-smoothly-update-a-flutter-animatedlist-without-using-a-globalkey-currents)